# How to access predefined Ansible modules in Custom Module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

Can someone please post a example on how to use a predefined Ansible module, in example `git` module in a Custom Module?

I was trying to convert the below tasks into a single Custom Module

```yaml
- name: Clone repo on Remote Hosts
  git:
    repo: "{{ git_repo_src }}"
    dest: "{{ git_repo_dest }}"

- name: Fetch template from single Remote Host
  run_once: true
  fetch:
    src: "{{ template_path }}/{{ template_file }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ templalte_file }}"
    flat: yes
    fail_on_missing: yes

- name: Template Remote Hosts
  template:
    src: "/tmp/{{ template_file }}"
    dest: "{{ templated_file_dest }}"
    owner: "{{ templated_file_owner }}"
    group: "{{ templated_file_group }}"
    mode: "{{ templated_file_mode }}"
```

Comment: no tasks posted.

Answer (score 0):

> the below tasks into a single custom module

So, what I'm hearing is that you'd like to orchestrate several built-in ansible actions, sometimes conditionally, or with looping, perhaps with some variables and with notifications, and maybe even the ability to store all that in a separate git repo, for easy inclusion/composition?

That [does sound familiar](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html)

Comment: Actually No!! I want to built a custom module to get templates from remote git repo. So for this i want to use predefined git module by ansible in my action plugin

Comment: Agree, this is not the answer

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the recommended approach and should be the accepted answer.