# Is it possible to use an Ansible Core Module within a Custom Module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

There is also this related question "[Access predefined ansible modules in custom module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834175/access-predefined-ansible-modules-in-custom-module)" but unfortunately without an helpful answer.

In general, I would like to create a Custom Module which uses some Core Modules.

If I e.g. want to use the Core Module [`file`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/file.py), I could of course look at the `main` function and extract the parts needed by importing the functions required.

So to create / remove a file this would require to use something like

```py
from ansible.modules.file import check_owner_exists, check_group_exists, keep_backward_compatibility_on_timestamps, ensure_file_attributes, ensure_absent
```

Then copy the required code and use it accordingly.

This seems like a huge workaround for something as simple as importing a core module in a custom module.

Are there any better ways to call the `file` module in a custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @U880D already pointed out, it is not possible call a module from another module.

The way around this is to use an `action` plugin (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-actions. The most prominent example is probably the template module:

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/template.py which contains the actual code
- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/template.py which only contains the documentation

In the hope it simplifies life for others, here is what I ended up using.

So to run the `file` module inside our own "module" we create `library/custom_file.py` (the "module" file containing only the documentation) with content

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Copyright: ...
# GNU General Public License v3.0+ (see COPYING or https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt)

DOCUMENTATION = r"""
---
<...>
"""
EXAMPLES = r"""
---
<...>
"""
RETURN = r"""
---
<...>
"""
```

and `action_plugins/custom_file.py` with

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from ansible.plugins.action import ActionBase

class ActionModule(ActionBase):
    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        result = super(ActionModule, self).run(tmp, task_vars)

        result.update(self._execute_module(
            module_name="file", module_args=file_args, task_vars=task_vars, tmp=tmp
        ))

        return result
```

now we can use this "module" in our playbook `test.yml`

```yaml
- name: Test my new module
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Run custom file module
      custom_file:
        path: /etc/foo.conf
        owner: foo
        group: foo
        mode: '0644'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your assumption

> *... for something as simple as importing a Core Module in a Custom Module ...*

you could review [Developing modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html)

> *A module is a reusable, standalone script that Ansible runs on your behalf, either locally or remotely. Modules interact with your local machine, an API, or a remote system to perform specific tasks like changing a database password or spinning up a cloud instance. Each module can be used by the Ansible API, or by the `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` programs.*

which indicates (at least for me) that such was never intended and therefore isn't possible. [The answer on "*How to access predefined Ansible Modules in Custom Module*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53845489/6771046) is helpful as it shows how to do it instead ...

> *Are there any better ways to call the `file` module in a Custom Module?*

... and which is in your case to use the `file` module within a playbook.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Calling an Ansible Module from another Ansible Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46903864/6771046)

  > *You can't execute a module from within other module, because modules in Ansible are self-contained entities, that are packaged on the controller and delivered to remote host for execution.*

---

What would indeed be possible is to import `module_utils` if there are any. See in example

- [Importing Ansible `module_utils`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910207/6771046)
- [How to import a `.py` file into an Ansible Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44175330/6771046)